# Integer partitions and dice result probabilities

Tags: combinatorics, partitions, project-euler

This is a [Project Euler question](https://projecteuler.net/problem=205), so no spoilers :]
I was going to try to solve it by first finding how many ways a certain sum can be acquired from a number of dice using `IntegerPartitions` . For example, using two 6-sided dice, there is only one way to get a sum of 2.

`IntegerPartitions[2, {2}, {1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4, 4, 5, 5, 6, 6}]`

I expected the answer to be `{1,1}`, but the output was `{{1,1},{1,1},{1,1}}`. I'm really confused now. Am I not using the function properly? If so, is there some other way that I could achieve the required result?

Bam XD

> `s = 0;
> For[i = 9, i <= 36, i++,
>  n1 = Length@
>    Flatten[(Permutations /@ IntegerPartitions[i, {9}, Range[4]]), 1];
>  For[j = 6, j < i, j++,
>   n2 = Length@
>     Flatten[(Permutations /@ IntegerPartitions[j, {6}, Range[6]]), 1];
>   p = n1/4^9*n2/6^6;
>   s = s + p]];
> N[s]`

Comment: `IntegerPartitions[2, {2}, Range[6]]`?

Comment: This doesn't consider the number of dice. If there are more than two, then there is no way of getting a sum of 2. I suspect that will also affect the results of getting higher sums, but maybe I'm wrong, lemme think about it >.> I think you're right <.< ... posted a stoopid question too soon, sorry ... shouldn't try to math before breakfast %\

Comment: solarmew, the second argument _is_ the number of dice, no? You are right you can't get a sum of 2 with 3 dice and   `IntegerPartitions[2, {3}, Range[6]]`  _does_ give `{}` as required.

Comment: I don't believe `IntegerPartitions` is the right tool for this.  Have you tried a brute force approach yet?

Comment: @ Mr.Wizard , I thought this was the brute force approach >.> I was going to go through all the possibilities of when the sum of one set of dice is greater than the sum of the other. That's just two nested loops.
I feel bad now. Should i delete the question, or would you like to shame-close it?

Comment: @Mr. Wizard , btw I love your solution to 67
https://projecteuler.net/thread=67&page=3#5679
it's so compact and beautiful @.@ ... one day ... one day i'll be able to Mathematica like that ...

Comment: Nicely done, and happy to be proven wrong.  Thanks regarding #67; I still like that bit of code.  I keep meaning to return to Project Euler (I stopped when I started participating on Stack Overflow) but I never do.  By brute force I meant `Tally`, which I what I used five years ago when I solved it.  (I can't believe it's been so long!)  You now have access to the forum solutions and many wonderful methods.  I am partial to the coefficient based methods which as I recall I learned as a result of this problem or one like it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I like this puzzle:

```
peter = Total /@ Tuples[Range[4], 9];
colin = Total /@ Tuples[Range[6], 6];
{sp, wp} = Transpose[Tally[peter]];
{sc, wc} = Transpose[Tally[colin]];
edp = EmpiricalDistribution[wp -> sp];
edc = EmpiricalDistribution[wc -> sc];
```

Counting the answer:

```
r = Tuples[{sp, sc}];
p = Pick[r, First@# > Last@# & /@ r];
probp = MapThread[#1 -> N[#2/Total[wp]] &, {sp, wp}];
probc = MapThread[#1 -> N[#2/Total[wc]] &, {sc, wc}];
NumberForm[Total[(#1 /. probp) (#2 /. probc) & @@@ p], 7]
```

Using probability functionality:

```
N[Probability[s > u, {s \[Distributed] edp, u \[Distributed] edc}]]
```

Or simulation:

```
pt = DiscreteUniformDistribution[{1, 4}];
cl = DiscreteUniformDistribution[{1, 6}];
fun[n_] := 
 N[Total[Table[
     Boole[Total@RandomVariate[pt, 9] > 
       Total@RandomVariate[cl, 6]], {n}]]/n]
```

and evaluate,e.g. `fun[1000000]`

Some visualization:

```
DiscretePlot[{PDF[edp, x], PDF[edc, x]}, {x, 2, 40}, 
 PlotStyle -> {Red, Black}, 
 PlotLegends -> {"Pyramidal Peter", " Cubic Colin"}]
```

[image]

I have not put my answer deliberately.